# Why am I not seeing duplicate values being printed out by multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

This is embarrassing, but I am unable to figure this simple code out.

The **AtomicReferenceTest** starts out multiple threads all referencing the same id generator.

The **IdGenerator** has no thread safety and maintains a single variable which is incremented by multiple threads and hence I fully expect threads to print out duplicate values already reported by other threads but that is not what I see.

When I print out the values I see no duplicate values, but the threads seems to see the value updated by other threads.

How can this be and what am I missing?

```
public class AtomicReferenceTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        AtomicReferenceTest.lockingIdGenerator();
    }

    public static void lockingIdGenerator() throws InterruptedException {
        // Change the value in the first parameter to allow more threads to run simultaneously
        IdGenerator idGenerator = new OneIdThreadGenerator();
        ExecutorService tpe = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            tpe.execute(new Runnable() {
                long id = 0;

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
                    System.out.println("Value of id in " + threadId + " is = " + id);
                    while (id < 1000) {
                        id = idGenerator.nextId();
                        System.out.println(threadId + " : " + id);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Stopping thread : " + threadId);
                }
            });
        }
        tpe.shutdown();
        tpe.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }
}
```

OneIdThreadGenerator:

```
/**
 * This class has no thread safety at all
 */
class OneIdThreadGenerator implements IdGenerator{
    private long id = 0;
    public long nextId() {
        id = id + 1;
        return id;
    }
}
```

My system specs are:

> Model Name:   MacBook Pro
>   Processor Name:   Intel Core i7
>   Processor Speed:  2.5 GHz
>   Number of Processors: 1
>   Total Number of Cores:    4
>   L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
>   L3 Cache: 6 MB
>   Memory:   16 GB

Comment: Interesting question, but just to make sure; can you add a short summary of your environment (CPU architecture; number of execution units, ie CPU cores and SMT if applicable; vendor and version of the JRE or JDK)?

Comment: I ran this code myself, and in fact saw many duplicates... and the value of id went up to 1009 for some threads

Comment: The JVM scheduler can be odd :P It can sometimes decide to behave nicely and give thread-safe behaviour, but don't count on it...

Comment: @tixopi your comment is misleading; the JVM scheduler is supposed to behave the way the JMM allows it to behave with regards to thread safety. In this case, the OP may not see errors as she expects to but the JMM does allow for duplicate values indeed.

Comment: @fge Sorry, yes of course I didn't mean to say that JVM would always behave that way. It was just meant to be a light hearted comment that trying to predict how the scheduler will behave can be a futile endeavour :P

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add my system specs. I do suspect it might be because of the CPU architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can this be and what am I missing?

I think your mistake is thinking that program with thread-safety issues will (always) *manifest* those issues when you run it.

The way the JVM spec is written, if you write your program following the rules set out in the section in the memory model, you are guaranteed that it will behave predictably across all Java platforms that implement the spec (correctly).  If you don't, then you don't have that guarantee.  But conversely, the spec does not say that the application *will* behave unexpectedly.

In general, the actual behavior of a program that has thread-safety issues is going to depend on:

- how many cores there are to run the program which will determine if there is true parallel execution, or pseudo-parallelism (platform specific),
- how the JIT compiler compiles your bytecodes to native code (potentially JVM version specific),
- the probability that two threads will attempt to use the same shared state unsafely in a short space of time (application specific), and
- a considerable degree of "luck"; i.e. influence of random / unpredictable factors.

If there is only one core used, then any pseudo-parallelism will be the result of the thread scheduler preempting one thread to allow another to run.  When that happens, there will be an implicit "memory barrier", causing memory caches to be flushed.  That will remove a major source of unpredictability.

---

In short, demonstrating the *presence* non-thread-safe behavior can be as difficult as demonstrating its *absence*.

Comment: Yes this definitely seems to be the case. I increased the no. of times nextId() is called to 10000 with a 100 threads and I could see that there were 4 duplicated created. I then increased to 500 threads and 100000 and only 3 were created. It definitely seems that this Mac behaves differently than the previous Windows laptop and machines I had used since it was very easy to prove non-thread safe code in my previous machines with just a 100 iterations and 10 threads.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicates aren't probable in your case, but possible. Non-determinism is tricky to test for and observe.

You can make it more likely by explicitly copying **id** and expanding the time window between the increment and the return to simulate being in the midst of the load, increment, and store steps of the **++** operation:

```
/**
 * This class has no thread safety at all
 */
class OneIdThreadGenerator implements IdGenerator{
    private long id = 0;
    public long nextId() {
        try {
            long nextId = id + 1;
            Thead.sleep(1000);
            id = nextId;
            return nextId;
        } catch (InterruptedException) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```